# Product Image Upload Error

Tags: magento-1.7

Below error while uploading images for Products:

> {"name":"img5.jpg", "type":"application/octet-stream","tmp_name":"C:/Windows/Temp/phpA0A2.tmp","error":0, "size"2456,"path":"C:/.../media/tmp/catalog/product","file":"/i/m/img5_2.jpg.tmp","url":"http://www.example.com/media/tmp/catlog/product/i/m/img5_2.jpg","cookie":{"name":"adminhtml","value":"ghhjgjfhghy95","lifetime":"3600":"path":"/","domain":'mysite.com'}}

I am using php 5.3 on Windows, everything else works fine.

I tried all possible ways which I know or found like giving permissions, to directories, setting c:/windows/temp on php.ini, all session variables are set to (No), I tried with User Agent (Yes) also but no success. Also mapped security settings on c:windows/temp with Media folder.

I noticed Magento not writing files on the temp directory, but i created a test file which is writing to temp dir. only Magento files are not being written?

Please anyone can support on this or any one knows some good free extension to manage product images? I prefer to have default upload working.

Comment: I have found a fix tried everything as mentioned above but the problem solved by replacing all the Magento original files again i didn't made any changes to the core files so no problem replacing but i think the problem was in var/package folder since i have deleted it may be by mistake :) i am so happy after spending almost 2 days i could fix the issue. many other having same problem please share with them. regards.

Comment: @saquib I am also facing the same issue with Magento ver. 1.4.1.1, Magento is able to upload images to media/tmp folder but the images are not visible in the admin as well as in the front end. How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Magento's official system requirements ([click here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements)) show that Magento is only supported on the following operating systems:

**Supported Operating Systems:** Linux x86, x86-64

Try switching to a linux based development environment and see if this solves your issue.